# individual toggle hide/show and toggle all hide/show doesnt cooparate properly. Any tip? (jquery)

Tags: jquery, toggle

I made filter for little work project and the last bug I need to solve is hide/show issue. When I show some of anotation by clicking the header and use the button later, the button show all of anotation, but it will not hide them all on second click. Do you know how to change the code to make it work properly? Thank you in advance!

```js
/* toggle button all anotation*/

$('#makeVisible').on('click', function () {


    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Show' ? 'Show' : 'Hide');

    $(".anotace").toggleClass("hide");
    $(".anotace").toggleClass("show");

    });


/*toggle one anotation to click its header */

        $('.nazev').click(function(){
          $(this).next(".anotace").slideToggle();
    })
```

```css
        .anotace {
          display: none;
        }


        .hide {
          display: none;
        }
        .show {
          display: block;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id='makeVisible'> Show </button>


<div class='beseda'> 
        <div class="nazev">Lorem</div>
        <div class="anotace">Ipsum </div>
    </div>
    
<div class='beseda'> 
        <div class="nazev">Lorem</div>
        <div class="anotace">Ipsum</div>
    </div>

<div class='beseda'> 
        <div class="nazev">Lorem</div>
        <div class="anotace">Ipsum</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's hiding all three 'Ipsum' annotations in my browser properly, as I think it should. The 'Lorem' annotations are not hidden (if that's what you meant), since you are only toggling the `show`/`hide` classes on annotations with the `anotace` class.

I suggest to only use either the `show` or the `hide` class by the way. So: make sure your annotations are visible by default and make the `hide` class override this, or the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$('#makeVisible').on('click', function() {
  var s = $(this).text() != 'Show'

  $(this).text(s ? 'Show' : 'Hide');

  if(s)
    $(".anotace:visible").slideToggle("show");
  else
    $(".anotace:not(:visible)").slideToggle("hide");

});
```

This will only show/hide those that aint shown/hidden.
So if you click on 1 of the `Lorem` and then `Show` button then the remaining 2 will toggle.

**Demo**

```js
/* toggle button all anotation*/

$('#makeVisible').on('click', function() {
  var s = $(this).text() != 'Show'

  $(this).text(s ? 'Show' : 'Hide');

  if(s)
    $(".anotace:visible").slideToggle("show");
  else
    $(".anotace:not(:visible)").slideToggle("hide");

});


/*toggle one anotation to click its header */

$('.nazev').click(function() {
  $(this).next(".anotace").slideToggle();
})
```

```css
.anotace {
  display: none;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id='makeVisible'>Show</button>


<div class='beseda'>
  <div class="nazev">Lorem</div>
  <div class="anotace">Ipsum </div>
</div>

<div class='beseda'>
  <div class="nazev">Lorem</div>
  <div class="anotace">Ipsum</div>
</div>

<div class='beseda'>
  <div class="nazev">Lorem</div>
  <div class="anotace">Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will work perfectly! Thank you for answer!